# Put additional text in the upper left corner of each TIKZ matrix node

Tags: tikz-matrix, teaching

I'd like to put a simple block letter in the corner of each cell (and leave each number in the center of the cell) to produce a labyrinth.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix[matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,
nodes={minimum size=3.5em,outer sep=0pt,anchor=center,draw,loosely dashed},
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth
] (mat) {
    -1& -2,1 & -2,3 & -2,2 & -4,7 & -5\ & -5,04 & -1,3\\
    -1,4 & -1,7 & -2,6 &  -2  & -4,5 &  -4,3 & -5,1 & -5,13 \\
    -1 & -4  & -3 &  -3,2  & -3  & -4,2 & -4,4 & -49  \\
    -2 & -1,5  & -1,1 & -3,7   &  -4 &  -4,1 & -11 & -100\\
};

\draw[thick] (mat-1-1.north west) rectangle (mat-4-8.south east); 

\draw[red,thick,dashed] plot coordinates {
(mat-1-1) (mat-2-1) (mat-2-2) (mat-1-2) (mat-1-3) (mat-2-3) (mat-3-3) (mat-3-4) 
(mat-4-4) (mat-4-6) (mat-2-6) (mat-2-5) (mat-1-5) (mat-1-7) (mat-2-7) (mat-2-8) 
(mat-4-8)  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you need exactly. Could be something like `\node[blue] at (mat-2-3.north west) {A};`?

Comment: The letter A has to be inside the cell and not on at the intersection of lines.

Comment: Then, with a shift? `\node[blue] at ([shift={(0.2,-0.2)}]mat-2-3.north west) {A};`?

Comment: It would be better if the number was a bit lower but it does the trick. Is there a shorter synthax than adding 32 lines like the one you provided for each cell ?

Comment: If the letter is always the same you can do it with a `\foreach`. Otherwise I don't know. Overlapping two matrices perhaps?

Comment: The letters are different for each cell. I thought of the overlapping trick, do you know how I can shift the text of all nodes ?

Comment: I would use `\node[below left] ... ` rather than the shift.  But this will have issues with the fact that the nodes are actually different sizes. Overlapping two matrices is a very clever idea, and all you need to do is adjust the location of the second matrix relative to the first.

Comment: I took the liberty of edit your MWE and added `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is overlapping two matrices, shifting the second (with the letters) respect to the first.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,
nodes={minimum size=3.5em,outer sep=0pt,anchor=center,draw,loosely dashed},
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth
] (mat) {
    -1& -2,1 & -2,3 & -2,2 & -4,7 & -5\ & -5,04 & -1,3\\
    -1,4 & -1,7 & -2,6 &  -2  & -4,5 &  -4,3 & -5,1 & -5,13 \\
    -1 & -4  & -3 &  -3,2  & -3  & -4,2 & -4,4 & -49  \\
    -2 & -1,5  & -1,1 & -3,7   &  -4 &  -4,1 & -11 & -100\\
};

\draw[thick] (mat-1-1.north west) rectangle (mat-4-8.south east); 

\draw[red,thick,dashed] plot coordinates {
(mat-1-1) (mat-2-1) (mat-2-2) (mat-1-2) (mat-1-3) (mat-2-3) (mat-3-3) (mat-3-4) 
(mat-4-4) (mat-4-6) (mat-2-6) (mat-2-5) (mat-1-5) (mat-1-7) (mat-2-7) (mat-2-8) 
(mat-4-8)  };

% this is for centering:
\useasboundingbox (mat-1-1.north west) rectangle (mat-4-8.south east); 

\matrix[matrix of nodes,blue,
nodes={minimum size=3.5em,outer sep=0pt,anchor=center},
] (mat2) at ([shift={(-0.5,0.4)}]mat) {% <-- change the shift if you need to
    H & B & C & D & E & F & G & H\\
    A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H\\
    A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H\\
    A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `[label={...}]` mechanism.  Labels are positioned at angles relative to the center (where the line hits the edge) rather than relative to the corners, so it would help to fix the aspect ratio of the parent node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[label position=139, 
  every label/.style={green, below right, inner sep=1pt}]
\node[draw, inner sep=1em, label=A] at (0,0) {1,1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]